# Finitely generated G, such that x^3 = 1 for all x, is finite?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

x^3 = e for any element x in finitely-generated group G. How to prove that G is finite?

Comment: See https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/HistTopics/Burnside_problem/ or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside_problem -- this follows because the Burnside group $B(m,3)$ is finite.

Comment: See Marshall Hall's book Group Theory, where this and other similar statements are proved.

Answer (score 2):

For a (partial) proof:

- First, check in some way that for any 4 elements in such a group we have $[x,[y,[z,t]]]=1$. I.e., in the free group, this commutator $[x,[y,[z,t]]]$ is a product of cubes. Thus, a single formula (equality in the free group $F_4$) does the job (I'll add it if I can compute it or if somebody knows it).
- As a consequence, every group of exponent 3 is 3-step nilpotent. The finiteness follows by dévissage.

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "dévissage" in this case?

Comment: @Pedro If $G$ is an $n$-step solvable finitely generated torsion group, its abelianization is finite, so $[G,G]$ has finite index hence is finitely generated, and hence is an $(n-1)$-step solvable finitely generated torsion group. So by induction on $n$ (starting with $n=1$), every $n$-step solvable finitely generated torsion group is finite.